# Undefined reference to "sleep" but I did include <unistd.h>

Tags: c, windows, winapi, sleep

Well, this must be a silly one. Here below is a can-not-be-simpler code in C. It can not compile saying "undefined reference to sleep". But I think I include all system header I need...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Test starts.\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Test ends.\n");

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "Undefined reference" sounds like it isn't linking to something it needs.

Comment: OS/Compiler?  Is there maybe more code than this with a typo?  This compiles and links with gcc 4.6.1.

Comment: @MengfeiMurphy, What compiler are you using? What command line are you typing to compile it? Tell us everything you can.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this at the top:

```
#ifdef __unix__
# include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
# include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * (x))
#endif
```

This code will allow you to use two different functions under the same name, that do quite the same thing. And it compiles under different platforms.

Also, parenthesizing the `(x)` argument ensures that the delay is right even if someone calls it like this `sleep(10+10)`

Comment: Wonderful! You are damn right! I am using win7 + `WinGW`. This is the first time I meet with portable issues in practice. Have you got any other similar examples?

Comment: Actually it doesn't come to my mind but you can do a lot of things in this way. It's clean and simple.

Comment: this does in fact work, besides my issues with the flags in codeblocks, i can now run code that i made on a linux system in windows thanks to this header

Comment: how buggy is this windows crap? having to define a macro to make this work when the header defined it? nice trick (even if I knew about the `Sleep` millis method) I have edited just in case someone passes `1+3` to the macro

Answer (score 2):

If you are running under the Windows operating system, include `windows.h` header file to your program and change `sleep()` to `Sleep()`.

The problem would get disappeared.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Windows' `Sleep()` function is in milliseconds, while *Nix's `sleep()` is in seconds. The *NIX equivalent of `Sleep()` is `usleep()`. See Wazabit's answer for the correct way to make code that uses `sleep()` portable.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem and looking at this code when i realized the 's' in sleep is capital .i.e. Sleep(10) but we both wrote sleep(10)

Comment: Neither `sleep()` nor `Sleep()` are part of the C standard. `sleep()` is part of the UNIX standard and `Sleep()` is provided in the `windows.h` file but they don't do the same thing. It's important to know what files you're linking and read the documentation for the functions they define. This is more than a typo situation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).