# Why I am getting undefined reference to sleep error?

Tags: c, include, sleep

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct subscriber {
    char phonenumber[20];
    char name[50];
    float amount;
} s;

void addrecords();
void listrecords();
void modifyrecords();
void deleterecords();
void searchrecords();
void payment();

char get;

int main()
{
    int password;
    int phonenumber;
    char choice;

    system("cls");

    printf
    ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n**********************************************************************");
    printf("\n\t\t---WELCOME TO THE TELECOM BILLING MANAGEMENT SYSTEM---");
    printf("\n\t\t****************************************************************");

    Sleep(2000);

    getch();

    system("cls");

    while (1) {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n enter\n A : for adding new records.\n L : for list of records");
        printf("\n M : for modifying records.\n P : for payment");
        printf("\n S : for searching records.");
        printf("\n D : for deleting records.\n E : for exit\n");

        choice = getche();
        choice = toupper(choice);

        switch (choice) {
        case 'P':
            payment();
        break;

        case 'A':
            addrecords();
            break;

        case 'L':
            listrecords();
            break;

        case 'M':
            modifyrecords();
            break;

        case 'S':
            searchrecords();
            break;

        case 'D':
            deleterecords();
            break;

        case 'E':
            system("cls");
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tTHANK YOU");
            printf("\n\n\n\n\n:\n\tFOR USING OUR SERVICE");
            Sleep(2000);
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            system("cls");
            printf("Incorrect Input");
            printf("\nAny key to continue");
            getch();

        }

    }

}
```

Error:

```
proj.c:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `Sleep'
proj.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `getch'
proj.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `getche'
proj.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `Sleep'
proj.c:(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `getch'
/tmp/cc4UYi0H.o: In function `addrecords':
proj.c:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `getch'
proj.c:(.text+0x340): undefined reference to `getche'
/tmp/cc4UYi0H.o: In function `listrecords':
proj.c:(.text+0x44c): undefined reference to `getch'
/tmp/cc4UYi0H.o: In function `deleterecords':
proj.c:(.text+0x5b2): undefined reference to `getch'
proj.c:(.text+0x632): undefined reference to `getch'
/tmp/cc4UYi0H.o: In function `searchrecords':
proj.c:(.text+0x791): undefined reference to `getch'
/tmp/cc4UYi0H.o: In function `payment':
proj.c:(.text+0xb1f): undefined reference to `getch'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried the solution given here ( [Undefined reference to "sleep" but I did include <unistd.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764295/undefined-reference-to-sleep-but-i-did-include-unistd-h) ) but it's still not working. I am using gcc on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: `getch()` and `getche()` (probably a typo for `getch()`) are not standard Unix functions either.  You need to compile with more warnings enable so you get compiler warnings about undefined functions instead of (or as well as) linker errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to come from Windows operating system. On Linux, the function `Sleep` does not exist (`Sleep`  is a function from Windows API!). Try `sleep` (from `<unistd.h>`) instead. As *alk* said, keep in mind the arguments of `Sleep` and `sleep` are different:

- `Sleep` takes a time in milliseconds;
- `sleep` takes a time in seconds.

Likewise, the `getch` function and the `cls`  shell command don't work with GNU/Linux.

Comment: Windows' `Sleep()` sleeps milliseconds, whereas unix' `sleep()` takes seconds. So one might like to add `#define Sleep(ms) sleep((ms)/1000)`

Answer (score 0):

getch() isn't part of standard library, It is a function from  library and You forgot to declare it use

Answer (score 0):

Your code is non-portable as per standard
remove `getch` and `cls`

for sleep use `sleep(n); //n is number of seconds`

for more info type on terminal : `man 3 sleep`

One suggestion also , when you port your code from windows to linux

try compiling with `gcc -Wall -Werror` option